# SQL 2008 R2 SP2 Linked Server - Exclude certain databases

Tags: sql, linked-server

I have a linked server and I would like to exclude 4 databases in the link.  Is there a way to "hide" them?  Currently the users access via the AD groups they are in.  Would I just revoke the AD groups?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by revoking access on the linked server to these AD groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the databases offline and they disappeared from the linked view.  These were there for reference only, so it made sense.